# member variables not updating in actionbar activity

Tags: android, android-activity, scope

two of my member variables which are global are somehow not getting the data i am assigning to them within my oncreate() method, below is my code. within the response() method of okhttp, the log.d prints the right size, but outside of that, it prints 0. see code below

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_grid);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }


   // for (int start = 0; start < 20; start++) {


        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {

            //using okHttp library to connect to imagesUrl and retrieve JSON Data
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(getImagePage(start)).
                            build();

            Call call = client.newCall(request);

            //runs the below code asynchronously
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "error from request");

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        //Log.v(TAG, jsonData);

                        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                            alertUserAboutError();
                        } else {

                            mSmalImagesUrls = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);
                            mBigImagesUrls.add(mSmalImagesUrls);
                            Log.d(TAG, mBigImagesUrls.size() + " big size");
                            Log.d(TAG, mSmalImagesUrls.size() + " small size");

                        }
                    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught :", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network is unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    //}

    Log.d(TAG, mBigImagesUrls.size() + " big size");
    Log.d(TAG, mSmalImagesUrls.size() + " small size");

}
```

tha last 3 Log.d statements print 0. i have no idea why. Please let me know what i am missing. thanks

Comment: you are aware that you're starting an asynchronous request, right? which means the last two `Log.d` lines won't have the "updated" value right away, you have to wait an unknown amount of time until your callback is called, then your globals get updated in the `onResponse` method.

Comment: Member variables are not global.